# No standard way to dereference/unwrap objects?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

When writing generic code, I often find myself in the situation in which the datatype `T` provided by the user of my lib might need to be directly a concrete type of some sort, but at the same time also a pointed type. This represents a problem when the generic operations in the lib are meant for the pointed type, and not for the pointer. Is there a standard way to dereference it? For example, something like this:

```
namespace std
{
template <typename T>
T& deref( T& t ){ return t; }

template <typename T>
T& deref( T* t ){ return *t; }

template <typename T>
T& deref( std::unique_ptr<T>& t ){ return *t; }

template <typename T>
T& deref( std::shared_ptr<T>& t ){ return *t; }

template <typename T>
T& deref( std::reference_wrapper<T>& t ){ return t.get(); }
}
```

So that my code will store `T` in his original form decided by the user, but will perform operations on `std::deref( t )` (e.g. `operator==` or `operator<<`)

Comment: You're not allowed to put things in the `std` namespace. Adding your own functions, classes, templates etc. makes your program ill-formed (IIRC, or is it even undefined behavior?)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, this is just an example. The question is if there is such a thing in STL or in the language in any form, I am not suggesting I am adding anything to `std` in my user code by any stretch.

Comment: Hm, I'm not aware of, so I suppose you'll have to write it yourself in the fashion that you presented above (not in namespace `std` then, of course). But instead of limiting to `std` smart pointers, I'd rather look with SFINAE if an `operator*` or `operator->` exists and then apply it, too.

Comment: [Checking function existence via SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)...

Comment: @Aconcagua I would use `std::is_pointer` but it should not work with reference_wrapper afaik. I really would expect something like `std::deref` this to be in the STL in some form, is it really not there?

Comment: What should be the behaviour with reference wrapped pointer?

Comment: @eerorika to get back `T` from `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, because sometimes the implicit cast to `T` is not gonna work, specially in generic code where normally `auto` is everywhere.

Comment: What do you expect from `T**`? no `nullptr` check for others?

Comment: @jarod42 I was not thinking about `T**` actually, but I would expect to return `T&` also in that case. For `nullptr` I'd say it's UB as much as it is UB also when you call `operator*` upon any `nullptr`, I wouldn't care

Comment: Can you give a real-life example for the usage of this functionality? So far, I can't really imagine a functionality that strips an undetermined number of levels of pointer (or other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there isn't any such functionionality. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/1312382), it's is not too heavy to write on your own (well, you did yourself already, this variant will extend to *anything* providing an `operator*`, though):

```
// first starting with some helper functions:

// return references as references!
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) doDeref(T& t, ...)
{
    return t;
}
// if some custom operator* returns a temporary, we cannot bind to normal
// reference, so we'll accept as rvalue reference instead:
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) doDeref(T&& t, ...)
{
    return std::move(t);
}
// specifically: anything that can be dereferenced:
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) doDeref(T& t, std::remove_reference<decltype(*t)>*)
//                                ^ to avoid trying to form pointer to reference
{
    return doDeref(*t, nullptr);
}
// a temporary that might be dereferencable:
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) doDeref(T&& t, std::remove_reference<decltype(*t)>*)
{
    return doDeref(*t, nullptr);
}
// reference wrapper; accept as const (!)
// be aware that return type still is non-const unless underlying
// type (i. e. T) is already const as well!
decltype(auto) doDeref(std::reference_wrapper<T> const& t)
{
    return doDeref(t.get(), nullptr);
}

// and finally: the main functions calling the helpers:

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) deref(T& t)
{
    return doDeref(t, nullptr);
}
// again to allow temporaries...
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) deref(T&& t)
{
    return doDeref(std::move(t), nullptr);
}
```

Bonus: That's even extensible for further types that do not fit in to normal de-referencing pattern (like `std::reference_wrapper`), just provide another overload calling the appropriate getter (if the class provides both const and non-const getter, you might need to provide all of the overloads for non-const and const ordinary references as well as for rvalue reference).